# Javascript module pattern

Tags: javascript

what is the difference below:

```
function test(){
    this.init=function(){//do something}
    this.some=function(){//do something}
    function other(){}
}
```

and

```
function test(){
    function init(){//do something}
    function some(){//do something}
    function other(){}

    return {'init':init, 'some':some};
}
```

Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mike has already pointed out, there is a difference on how they need to be invoked (the first version requires `new` while the second doesn't).

That said, if these are being used for actual modules (instead of just objects) and the functions in the module call each other then there is a difference.

In the second case the functions can reference each other directly (static binding).

```
function init(){
    some(17);
}
```

But in the first case they would reference each other via dynamic binding through the `this`:

```
this.init = function(){
    this.some(17); 
}
```

This means that in the first case (with the `this`) the init function must be always called as `module.init()` and cannot be passed to a callback

```
setTimeout( module.init, 1000 );
//this line will does not work with the `this.init` variation
//but will work fine in the second version
```

Because I don't like having to retype the function names as in the second version, I personally prefer to use the following style in my modules:

```
var module = (function(){

    var M = {}; //private namespace.
                //decouples from the actual name and I
                //can always use the same letter (for consistency)

    M.init = function(){
        M.some(17);
    };

    M.some = function(){
        //
    }

    function other(){ ... }

    return M;
}());
```

Answer (score 6):

The first example:

```
var object = new test();
object.init();
```

the second example:

```
var object = text(); // no new
object.init();
```